# Thrift 0.8.0 fails to install at ./configure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

i am trying to install thrift-0.8.0 on my ubunto 20 VM hosted on a windows 10 machine.
i get the last three lines in after i execute the command :

**checking for setsockopt in -lsocket...no
checking for BN_init in -lybcrypto ...no
configure: error:  "ERROR: libcrypto required."**

i have installed libss-dev package.
i also tried this solution i saw in a post here :
**LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/ssl/lib' LIBS='-ldl' ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/thrift --with-php --with-boost=/usr/local/boost**
i tried :
**../thrift-0.8.0/configure CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/ssl/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/ssl/lib CXXFLAGS=-DMINGW**

nothing worked and i feel so lost, can you guys suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest version `0.15.0` from [git repo](https://github.com/apache/thrift):

```
sudo apt install automake bison flex g++ git libboost-all-dev \
libevent-dev libssl-dev libtool make pkg-config

git clone -b 0.15.0 https://github.com/apache/thrift.git
cd thrift
git branch
./bootstrap.sh
./configure --disable-dependency-tracking
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I wish they'd update the apt.. it's still on V0.13.0

Comment: @Erik The active branch is `0.16.0` , all branches are [listed here](https://github.com/apache/thrift/branches/all)

Comment: Im speaking about APT package manager..